# Owncloud php-apc Error

Tags: php, linux, debian, apc, owncloud

I have a question regarding ownCloud in use with php-apc.I ownCloud instaled on a Debian Jessie Server.The following steps I performed to enable **php-apc:**

1 **apt-get install php-apc**

2 /var/www/html/owncloud/config/config.php

added the following line: **'memcache.local' => '\ OC \ \ Memcache APC'**

OwnCloud now displays the following **error** in the log file:

**=> Error PHP OC\HintException: Memcache \OC\Memcache\APC not available for local cache at /var/www/html/owncloud/lib/private/memcache/factory.php#94**

Can someone help me with a solution?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you even do a [cursory search for the error](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=34301)?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Of course not Sam, why bother Google when we all have nothing better to do.

Comment: Yes, but I could find no fault. I looked at the entry Apc via phpinfo and everything seems to work. And an hour Googling has not helped me.

Comment: I think php-apc work with owncloud already but this Error is allready displayed in the log file

Comment: In each room the same these prejudices ... Sorry that I ask @RiggsFolly

Comment: Jay's link gives you a number of options, have you tried them all?

Comment: Yes I have been in this forum before I asked here.

But I have the solution ... Restart The Server ... Then All works :) But the funny thing is that I have already restart it after instalation.